# Note taking application with GTD support and encryption

Tags: project-management, note-taking, encryption

I've been using Evernote for quite some time but I feel that the service just doesn't keep up anymore. I'm looking for alternatives with GTD support(or some form of todo management system), cross-platform and encryption that can be self hosted or stored on Drive or Dropbox in an encrypted state. Is there something like this?

Comment: I use [Todoist](https://win.todoist.com/overview). It [integrates well with the GTD workflow](https://win.todoist.com/gtd). It isn't self-hosted, but it uses SSL encryption to store data for premium accounts. Is that okay or does it have to be stored on Drive or Dropbox?

Comment: No it doesn't have to use Dropbox or Drive, that was just a suggestion.  I would prefer not to have them hosted by first party as I got some sensitive stuff to store with my tasks, such as clientele info. I would like not having both the encryption part and the hosting part in the same basket. I would like them to separate.